Can't convert it to excel from dataframe due to not enough space, but i have space on my disk
so i have a dataframe that i want to proceed using this code :
# Create an Excel writer object
with pd.ExcelWriter(output_file_path, engine='xlsxwriter') as writer:
    # Write the first DataFrame to a sheet named 'grouped_df_tph_sku'
    tph_summary.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='tph_summary', index=False)
    
    # Write the second DataFrame to a sheet named 'df'
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='df', index=False)

unfortunately i got an error liket this
FileCreateError: [Errno 28] No space left on device
even tough i check it to my disk, i have 218 gb free on my disk. the dataframe itself only had 200K rows and 55 columns. but still no idea why this is happen
problem caused by the code even tough it is no idea what is going on

Are you using Linux? if answer is Yes, please post your output "df -h" on terminal

Please show the full traceback to that error too.

Even if space exists, xlsxwriter might be using a temporary directory (/tmp or equivalent) that could be low on space. Check and free up space there.

pardon my knowledge, but where is this /tmp located? how to find out?

hello there, I believe, even with temp folder hidden, still if capacity of a drive in that folder is occupied, it will be shown on the computer drive's space.

Seems a lot of rows. it is probably RAM problem as all the data of conversion first transfers into RAM. if that data is more than capacity of your RAM then it will raise an error. try reducing your dataframe into several smaller dataframes.

you can verify whether the memory is enought by some log after each step and then set enough python memory.
like this:
    # Write the first DataFrame to a sheet named 'grouped_df_tph_sku'
    log_memory_usage();
    tph_summary.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='tph_summary', index=False)

    log_memory_usage();
    # Write the second DataFrame to a sheet named 'df'
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='df', index=False)
    log_memory_usage();


# Here is the memory test log demo:

import psutil
import time
import logging

# Set the log file name and log format
logging.basicConfig(filename='memory_log.txt', 
                    level=logging.INFO, 
                    format='%(asctime)s - %(message)s')

def log_memory_usage():
    # Get the system's memory information
    memory_info = psutil.virtual_memory()
    
    # Extract total memory and available memory (remaining memory)
    total_memory = memory_info.total / (1024 ** 3)  # Convert to GB
    available_memory = memory_info.available / (1024 ** 3)  # Convert to GB
    
    # Log the information
    logging.info(f'Total Memory: {total_memory:.2f} GB, Available Memory: {available_memory:.2f} GB')

